# How to obfuscate web project (in form of .war) running on glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, proguard, war, obfuscation

Seeking steps to obfuscate my web project (in the form of .war) which uses glassfish4. I am trying with proguard tool. It creates the obfuscated war successfully but while deploying it at glassfish it fails.

Error : remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: . Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy failed.

Answer (score 0):

did you verify in the war if there is something in WEB-INF/classes ? normally all .class are skipped maybe the problem come from here ?